# delete a matched string in a condition, PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, parsing, text-parsing

the idea is to import a csv, and then if the value "infohostname" contains a nullorwithespace delete the entire line

```
    Function Last_NAS_Parse {

$Import_IP = Import-Csv -Path "$destination_RAW_NAS\audit_nas_8_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).txt" -Header @("date","infohostname","Version","SMTP","Value_1","Value_2","Value_3","Value_4","Value_5","Value_6","Value_7","Value_8","Value_9")
$Import_IP | ForEach-Object {
   if ( [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.infohostname)


  }
```

But don't know how can i delete the line after this is selected, thanks.

Comment: Firstly, your code is missing parentheses and brackets in order to compile as posted. Is your goal to delete the entire row from the file, or simply clear it?

Comment: @trebleCode the idea is just to delete the entire row from the file

Answer (score 2):

IMO you don't need a function just a `Where-Object`:

```
$Header = ("date","infohostname","Version","SMTP","Value_1","Value_2","Value_3","Value_4","Value_5","Value_6","Value_7","Value_8","Value_9")
$Import_IP = Import-Csv -Path "$destination_RAW_NAS\audit_nas_8_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).txt" -Header $Header | 
   Where-Object {![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.infohostname)}
```

But of course you could wrap that in a function
(but a function without passed parameters and returned values isn't a real function)

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the results and store only objects where that boolean evaluation is true, and create a new file. In order to delete the row of the existing file, I believe you'd have to convert it to XLS/X and access it as a COM object

```
$results = @()
Function Last_NAS_Parse {

    $Import_IP = Import-Csv -Path C:\path\to\file.csv
    $Import_IP | ForEach-Object {
        if ( [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.infohostname)) 
        {
            Out-Null
        }
        else
        {
            $results += $_
        }
    }
}

Last_NAS_Parse
$results | Export-CSV "C:\export\path\of\newfile.csv"
```